# Is there an azure cli command that gets the threads and comments on a PR?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there an `az cli` command that gets the threads and comments on a PR?

PR's can be listed with:
`az repos pr list --organization $organization --project "$project" --repository $repo`

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/pr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-repos-pr-list)

The REST API has this endpoint, which gets the threads and comments:
`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/threads?api-version=7.1-preview.1`

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-threads/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

example output cropped:

```
    "value": [
        {
            "pullRequestThreadContext": null,
            "id": 111111,
            "publishedDate": "2024-02-19T16:00:00.000Z",
            "lastUpdatedDate": "2024-02-19T16:00:00.000Z",
            "comments": [],
            "status": "active",
            "threadContext": null,
            "etc": "etc"
        },
        {
            "pullRequestThreadContext": null,
            "id": 123456,
            "publishedDate": "2024-02-19T16:00:00.000Z",
            "lastUpdatedDate": "2024-02-19T16:00:00.000Z",
            "comments": [
                    "content": "Some comment on the PR appears in this field",
                    "publishedDate": "2024-02-19T16:00:00.000Z",
                    "lastUpdatedDate": "2024-02-19T16:00:00.00Z",
                    "lastContentUpdatedDate": "2024-02-19T16:00:00.000Z",
                    "commentType": "text",
                    "etc": "etc"`
            ]
        }
            ]
            "etc"
            "etc"
}
```

But there does not seem to be a way to use `az repos` to get threads and comments.

(I am specifically looking for PR's that have open comments, with `"status": "active"` and not `"status": "fixed"`: since our automation should not close these PR's. Atm we have no way of differentiating between PR's except for using the REST API, ideally we do not use both REST API and  az cli, az cli is more user friendly, so has my preference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get threads with `az devops`, you may use `invoke` subcommand. To get threads:

```
az devops invoke --area git --resource pullRequestThreads --org https://dev.azure.com/<your_org> --route-parameters project=<your_project> repositoryId=<repo_name> pullRequestId=<pr_id> --http-method GET --api-version 5.1-preview -o json
```

To get comments in threads:

```
az devops invoke --area git --resource pullRequestThreadComments --org https://dev.azure.com/<your_org> --route-parameters project=<your_project> repositoryId=<repo_name> pullRequestId=<pr_id> threadId=<id_from_previous_cmd> --http-method GET --api-version 5.1-preview -o json
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. Do you know where there is more documentation on this subcommand?

Comment: @Roelof it exists but not a lot )) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/azure/devops?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-invoke

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **`az repos pr list`**, Use **`az repos pr show`** command to get the comments from the ***PR ID*** of the repository. Unfortunately, According to this **[MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/pr?view=azure-cli-latest#commands)** there's no direct command to get the comments from **`az repos`**.

**Commands:-**

```bash
az login
az repos pr show --id 11 --org https://dev.azure.com/sid24desai0738/
```

***Output:-***

[image]

[image]

Also, You can also use Powershell command to easily call any Azure Rest API, to call the Rest API mentioned in the question to [***list Repos by PR ID***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-threads/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP):-

**Commands:-**

```
$PAT = "qxxxxxxxxizikif6js4o37sbt7a"
$OrgName = "xxxxi0738"
$ProjectName = "AzureDevops"
$ApiVersion = "7.1-preview.1"

$threads = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/$ProjectName/_apis/git/repositories/xxxxxxb1880/pullRequests/11/threads?api-version=$ApiVersion" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")))}

$threads.value
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but we would rather focus on only using `az cli` to keep code base consistent and not use direct API calls.